# How to parse AWS S3 XML in android using xml parser or any other parser .?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xmlpullparser

How to read this amazonaws s3 XML in android using xml parser.
i user parser but now working and provide null value. how to resolve this issue thanks in advance

**AWS S3 XML_FILE:**

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <Name>myMp3</Name>
   <Prefix />
   <Marker />
   <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
   <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
   <Contents>
      <Key>Jumykhutby2019/</Key>
      <LastModified>2019-02-10T11:11:20.000Z</LastModified>
      <ETag>"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
      <Size>0</Size>
      <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
   </Contents>
   <Contents>
      <Key>Jumykhutby2019/002  5 اکتوبر 2018 شیخ امین .MP3</Key>
      <LastModified>2019-02-13T19:44:25.000Z</LastModified>
      <ETag>"d0f7c653c582b89e14776d457ab4fcdb-6"</ETag>
      <Size>47186907</Size>
      <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
   </Contents>
   <Contents>
      <Key>Jumykhutby2019/juma01.mp3</Key>
      <LastModified>2019-02-13T21:49:37.000Z</LastModified>
      <ETag>"a7bae0567c8e53f2074fffd95dce5404-3"</ETag>
      <Size>42532595</Size>
      <Owner>
         <ID>3858f4d0f71aa7b7411c83175a73742c9ebed9bda893722d34877751e84e5f02</ID>
      </Owner>
      <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
   </Contents>

</ListBucketResult>
```

**Java code:**

```
static final String KEY_ITEM = "Contents";
static final String KEY_ID = "Key";
static final String KEY_NAME = "LastModified";
static final String KEY_COST = "Size";
static final String KEY_DESC = "StorageClass";
```

**Method 1:**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(XML_FILE); // getting XML

Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
    map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
    map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
    map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    menuItems.add(map);
}
Log.i("OutPut",menuItems.toString() );
```

**Method 2:**

```
 ArrayList<MeanSetGet> list;
 URL URL = new URL(wording[0]);
 XMLReader mXMLReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();;
 Log.e("OutPut", mXMLReader.toString());
```

**XML Parser:**

```
class XMLParser {
    XMLParser() {
    }

    String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }

    Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return doc;
    }

    private String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node child;
        if (elem != null) {
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

**Dependency i used:**

```
   implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
```